# Como trabalhar com relacionamento 1 para 1 no core data?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, relacionamento

Como realizo operações relacionando entidades no Core Data?
 Essas operações irá relacionar dados entre 2 entidades, sendo do tipo 1 para 1.

Quero relacionar o atributo imagem da tabela 1 com o campo pathimagem da tabela 2.

Exemplo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria de saber se isso fará com que o campo da imagem da tabela 1 "guarde" o valor contido no campo pathimagem da tabela 2... ou que seja equivalente a isso?

Se alguem souber um link para um bom tutorial explicando isso detalhadamente será bem vindo também!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Contornei este questionamento, fazendo um fetch dos dados e fazendo um comparação entre eles, e adicionando o valor no em um determinado campo, assim que o valor "flag" do objeto era encontrado.